# Parsing data more within substring-before and substring-after

Tags: regex, xslt, substring

I'm parsing data from an incoming field and the field has a large amount of data in it. Basically without showing the data I would like to get that shows up after the word `ORIGINATOR:` and everything before the words `ORIGINATOR BANK:` but not necessarily. Sometimes after the word `ORIGINATOR:` there is a long number that sometimes starts with a letter. I don't want that. I want what shows up after.

Here is an example:

```
SENDERS REFERENCE: 123456789ORIGINATOR: /1234567894 XYZ COMPANY 123 ANYSTREET NEW YORK NY 12345ORIGINATOR BANK: 123456789
```

So from the above I would only want the words `XYZ COMPANY` only.

Here is the code I'm using to get after `ORIGINATOR` and before `ORIGINATOR BANK`:

```
<OriginatorCompanyInfo><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(wd:Addenda,'ORIGINATOR: '),'ORIGINATOR BANK:')"/></OriginatorCompanyInfo>
```

brings up

```
<OriginatorCompanyInfo>/1234567894 XYZ COMPANY 123 ANYSTREET NEW YORK NY 12345</OriginatorCompanyInfo>
```

I tried to use `(\s+\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+)\s+)` within this code but it is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Maria

```
<OriginatorCompanyInfo2><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(wd:Addenda,'ORIGINATOR:(\s+\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+)\s+)'),'ORIGINATOR BANK:')"/></OriginatorCompanyInfo2>
```

nothing came up - just blank

```
<OriginatorCompanyInfo2/>
```

Comment: XSLT1.0 does not support regex.

Comment: More precisely, the arguments of the `substring-after()` function are *strings*, not *regex patterns*. Please clarify which version of XSLT your processor supports. A more accurate description of the "long number that sometimes starts with a letter" would also be useful: in your example, it starts with a "/" - is that "a letter"? If so, what else is?

Comment: This kind of string manipulation can usually be done with XSLT 1.0 but it can get very difficult; in 2.0 it becomes very much easier using regular expressions. You shouldn't be asking XSLT questions without saying what version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, you may be able to use this instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(wd:Addenda, '.*ORIGINATOR: (\D?\d+ )?(.*)ORIGINATOR BANK.*', '$2')" />
```

to extract the wanted substring.